# How do I update a string attribute with xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, bash, command-line-interface, xmlstarlet

```
$ xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/parse-plugins/mimeType/plugin[@id='parse-html']/@id" -v 'parse-tika' conf/parse-plugins.xml
```

Why doesn't it replace the plugin id of mimetpes currently using parse-html plugin?

From [xmlstarlet documentation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.pdf):

> Update value of an attribute

`xml ed -u ’/xml/table/rec[@id=3]/@id’ -v 5 xml/tab-obj.xml`

I'm working on [nutch parse-plugins.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/branches/branch-1.3/conf/parse-plugins.xml?view=co&content-type=text/plain).

Comment: It works for me.  Do you get an error of some kind?

Comment: @Mark - does the file content change?

Comment: Yes, it rewrites the file for me.

Comment: (There's one `parse-html` attribute left, but of course that's at a different path within the document.)

Comment: hmmm..some how re-opening the file (for the nth time) I see it changed!

Comment: Well, I guess we can close the file on that one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Mark pointed out, it works! To check that things changed use

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/parse-plugins/mimeType/plugin[@id='parse-html']" conf/parse-plugins.xml
```

or the last-modified file attribute.